# Flutter: Image.memory() fails with bytes != null': is not true -- when there IS data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display an image based on (base64) data coming from a backend, but I keep getting the error `bytes != null': is not true.`

Here's my code:

```
class _FuncState extends State<Func> {
  Uint8List userIconData;
  
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI();
  }

  void updateUI() async {
    await getUserIconData(1, 2, 3).then((value) => userIconData = value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        Container(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: Image.memory(userIconData).image, // <--- problem here
            maxRadius: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Helper code:

```
Future<Uint8List> getUserIconData(
  role,
  id,
  session,
) async {
  var url = Uri.https(kMobileAppAPIURL, kMobileAppAPIFolder);
  var response = await http.post(url, body: {
    'method': 'getUserProfilePic',
    'a': id.toString(),
    'b': role.toString(),
    'c': session.toString(),
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return base64Decode(data['img']);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I have stepped through the code with a debugger and I have confirmed the helper function is returning the correct series of bytes for the image.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Further note.  The error also says:

> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple; if you take a look at your code you should be able to follow through this sequence of operations.

1. The widget is created. **No action.**  *At this point userIconData is null.*
2. `initState` is called. **async http call is initiated.** *userIconData == null*
3. `build` is called. **build occurs, throws error.** *userIconData == null*
4. http call returns. **userIconData is set.** *userIconData == your image*

Due to not calling `setState`, your build function won't run again. If you did, this would happen (but you'd still have had the exception earlier).

6. `build` is called. **userIconData is set.** *userIconData == your image*

The key here is understanding that asynchronous calls (anything that returns a future and optionally uses `async` and `await`) do not return immediately, but rather at some later point, and that you can't rely on them having set what you need in the meantime. If you had previously tried doing this with an image loaded from disk and it worked, that's only because flutter does some tricks that are only possible because loading from disk is synchronous.

Here are two options for how you can write your code instead.

```dart
class _FuncState extends State<Func> {
  Uint8List? userIconData;
  
  // if you're using any data from the `func` widget, use this instead
  // of initState in case the widget changes.
  // You could also check the old vs new and if there has been no change
  // that would need a reload, not do the reload.
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Func oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    updateUI();
  }
  
  void updateUI() async {
    await getUserIconData(widget.role, widget.id, widget.session).then((value){
      // this ensures that a rebuild happens
      setState(() =>  userIconData = value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          // this only uses your circle avatar if the image is loaded, otherwise
          // show a loading indicator.
          child: userIconData != null ? CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: Image.memory(userIconData!).image,
            maxRadius: 20,
          ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another way to do the same thing is to use a FutureBuilder.

```dart
class _FuncState extends State<Func> {
  // using late isn't entirely safe, but we can trust
  // flutter to always call didUpdateWidget before
  // build so this will work.
  late Future<Uint8List> userIconDataFuture;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Func oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    userIconDataFuture =
        getUserIconData(widget.role, widget.id, widget.session);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: userIconDataFuture,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: Image.memory(snapshot.data!).image,
                    maxRadius: 20);
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the loading indicator is just one option; I'd actually recommend having a hard-coded default for your avatar (i.e. a grey 'user' image) that gets switched out when the image is loaded.

Note that I've used null-safe code here as that will make this answer have better longevity, but to switch back to non-null-safe code you can just remove the extraneous `?`, `!` and `late` in the code.

Comment: Nice clear explanation, thank you.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: That worked perfectly - I was so close.  Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear to me. `userIconData` is `null` when you pass it to the `Image.memory` constructor.

Either use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or a condition to check if `userIconData` is null before rendering image, and manually show a loading indicator if it is, or something along these lines. Also you'd need to actually set the state to trigger a re-render. I'd go with the former, though.